# Mongo, spring and serialization

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using mongoDB database with spring data. Is there an equivalent to hibernate annotation    `@Type(type = "serializable")` in spring data for mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring data mongo will transparently bind `byte[]` to mongo BinData, without a need for any annotation.

If this is not enough for you, you can write custom converter for your type:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters

However having binary blob doesn't allow any querying or aggregation on the data, so it is usually better to have it in "json" form.

Comment: I understand benefits from storing data in "json" form but I need this as temporary solution. I think this custom converters will definitely work for me!